# Creating a django query that will retrieve the previous and next object based on alphabetical order

Tags: python, django, model, alphabetical

I have a django model that looks something like this:

```
class Definition
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    text = models.TextField()
```

If I do the following query:

```
animal = Definition.objects.get(name='Owl')
```

and if I have the following definitions with these names in my database:

```
Elephant, Owl, Zebra, Human
```

is there a way to do a django query(ies) that will show me the previous and the next Definitions based on the `animal` object based on alphabetical order of the `name` field in the model?

I know that there are ways of getting previous/next based on `datetime` fields, but I am not so sure for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any way of doing this in less than three queries.

```
target = 'Owl'
animal = Definition.objects.get(name=target)
previous_animal = Definition.objects.order_by('name').filter(name__lt=target)[0]
next_animal = Definition.objects.order_by('name').filter(name__gt=target)[0]
```

Comment: +1 Nice! Didnt know you could use lt and gt on strings. Very handy :).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this like I just did...

heres my solution... it also loops(so if on last item it shows first item as next and if on first item shows last item as previous)

```
    def get_previous_by_title(self):
        curr_title = self.get_object().title
        queryset = self.my_queryset()
        try:
            prev = queryset.filter(title__lt=curr_title).order_by("-title")[0:1].get()
        except Video.DoesNotExist:
            prev = queryset.order_by("-title")[0:1].get()
        return prev

    def get_next_by_title(self):
        curr_title = self.get_object().title
        queryset = self.my_queryset()
        try:
            next = queryset.filter(title__gt=curr_title).order_by("title")[0:1].get()
        except Video.DoesNotExist:
            next = queryset.order_by("title")[0:1].get()
        return next
```

i have custom querysets based on user level so could just set the queryset as a normal queryset like... Video.objects.all() but anyplace I repeat code more than once I make a function